# How to implement OpenXml GradientFill in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, openxml

I am not suceeding in translating into vb.net some code which works in c#.

The code is from StackOverflow article:
[How to use a gradient fill (GradientFill) with ClosedXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474418/how-to-use-a-gradient-fill-gradientfill-with-closedxml)

I can get most of it correctly except this:

```
 GradientFill gradientFill = new GradientFill() { Degree = 354 };
    gradientFill.Append(new GradientStop() { Position = 0D, Color = new Color() { Rgb = "FF00FF00" } });
    gradientFill.Append(new GradientStop() { Position = 0.49D, Color = new Color() { Rgb = "FF00FF00" } });
    gradientFill.Append(new GradientStop() { Position = 0.51D, Color = new Color() { Rgb = "FFFFFFFF" } });
    gradientFill.Append(new GradientStop() { Position = 1D, Color = new Color() { Rgb = "FFFFFFFF" } });
```

Any help would be super apreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need a `With` and a `.` to do that in VB.NET, e.g.

```
Dim myGradientFill As New GradientFill() With {.Degree = 354}
myGradientFill.Append(New GradientStop() With {.Position = 0D, .Color = New Color() With {.Rgb = "FF00FF00"}})
```